# Segmentation Fault in C when passing an int to scanf()?

Tags: c

Please help me to debug my program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{

   int n = 1,t;

    printf("How many Peanut Butter sandwiches do you want?");

        scanf("%d", t);

   while( n <= t )
   {

      printf("Making Sandwhitch no. %d\n", n);
      n++;

   }

   return 0;
}
```

Every time I submit, it shows segmentation fault (core dumped).
What to do?

Comment: Hint: the problem is in `scanf` parameter...

Comment: *What to do?* Turn on all compiler warnings - and actually read them.

Comment: Don't try to write data into whatever is being pointed at by "t"? Maybe check the docs for scanf again.

Comment: **always** check the return value of `scanf` (although I doubt your program will get to that point). And note the type of parameter you need to pass.

Comment: The `%d` scanf format specifier expects a corresponding argument of type `int *`. You have supplied an argument (`t`) of type `int`. You should replace `t` with `&t`.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) please consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` takes pointer as parameters, so to use it with your `t` here, you must use `scanf()` this way: `scanf("%d", &t);`

See this for more informations about pointers: [Pointers in c](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` work with variable address. so pass argument address like bellow :

```
scanf("%d", &t);
```

`&t` point out to `t` address.